# Azure Cloud Service - no environment variables being set

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

The roles in my Cloud Service aren't getting any custom environment variables set. --Meaning if I enumerate the results of a call to `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()`, only the standard environment variables are set (things like `PATH` or the user id).

When I debug the Cloud Service locally using the emulator, the envvars are there, so I'm kind of at a loss here.

The relevant .csdef:

```
<WebRole name="..." vmsize="Small">
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="FirstSetting" />
      <Setting name="AnotherSetting" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Runtime>
      <Environment>
        <Variable name="FirstSettingEnvVar">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/ConfigurationSettings/ConfigurationSetting[@name='FirstSetting']/@value" />
        </Variable>
        <Variable name="SecondSettingEnvVar">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/ConfigurationSettings/ConfigurationSetting[@name='SecondSetting']/@value" />
        </Variable>
      </Environment>
    </Runtime>
```

and the relevant .cscfg:

```
<Role name="...">
    <Instances count="2" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="FirstSetting" value="ABCD" />
      <Setting name="SecondSetting" value="WXYZ" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
</Role>
```

Comment: Note to anyone stumbling upon this question: this stopped happening for us after a Service Fabric SDK version bump.